# Module update shows success but nothing happens

Tags: module, prestashop

I have developed a module for PrestaShop and integrated the auto-update logic for modules into it and now I'm trying to test it, because the changes were submitted in the marketplace.

I get the message that there's an update for my module and if I click on "Update it!" button it shows the success message "All modules updated successfully.", but in the end nothing happend. The update button is still there and no upgrade script was run.

Did anyone came across something like this? I can't find the root cause for this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by three kind of facts :
- There is a licence with that module and you can't update to the new one because it expired. Prestashop never fixed this.
- Installation / Update script isn't working as it should and returns OK (true in fact) when it's triggered, whatever happened.
- Permissions problems, which returns no errors but doesn't work anyway.

I encourage you to check your folders permissions first and then try to download manually on Prestashop's Website if necessary.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you know which license file needs to be updated? The Installation script is working fine and the update one I tested it somehow manually by decreasing the module version in PrestaShop's db and then force it to upgrade and this worked fine again(script was run). And regarding the permissions I reviewed them and everything seems ok, but I'll check them again. The thing is it works for other modules, only for this one it doesn't perform any action.

Comment: If you bought the module it's related to Prestashop addons not on a file :)